# How to write index on the bottom of a word?

Tags: indexing

I want to write index on the bottom of a word

```
Word(min a element b)
```

I want to put "min a element b" exactly on the bottom of "Word", I don't know how suppose I do, I'd try Word$_{min a element b}$, but it isn't fulfill my intention.
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a concrete word and `amsmath` can be used, a solution is very simple:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\def\Word{\operatorname{Word}\limits}

\[
\Word_{\textrm{min a element b}}\limits
\]

or $\Word_{\textrm{min a element b}}\limits$


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works, sorry for ask such question, I'm very beginner of this.

Comment: @Yagami Your question was good. The general solution might be more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}
This is a \stackunder[1pt]{Word}{\scriptsize min a element b} in text.

And in math wit a deep underset:
\[
y = A + \stackunder[5pt]{Word}{\scriptsize min a element b}
\]
and in math using width of base word (ignoring underset width):
\[\def\useanchorwidth{T}
y = A + \stackunder{Word}{\scriptsize underset}
\]
Then there is this, a left-aligned, multi-line understack:
\[
\stackunder{Word}{\scriptsize\Longstack[l]{Four score\\ and seven\\ years ago}} = mx + b
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, there many ways to express this statement, I could add my reference. I'd try to learn more.